# thor::Animator playing only one frame

Tags: c++, animation, sfml, thor

I've been trying to animate an sf::Sprite with Thor 2.1, but as of now my sprite only displays one frame of each animation, not going through all of them.

I've got a sample spritesheet out of one of SFML's tutorials for spritesheets:

[image: Test spritesheet]

My code (schematic code, not the whole):

```
#include<SFML/Window.hpp>
#include<SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<SFML/System.hpp>
#include<SFML/Main.hpp>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <Thor/Animations.hpp>

int main()
{

sf::Texture texPlayer;
texPlayer.create(96, 128);
if (!texPlayer.loadFromFile(workingDirectory + "\\textures\\animtest.png"))
{
    std::cout << "can't load" << std::endl;
}

sf::Sprite sprPlayer;
sprPlayer.setTexture(texPlayer);

thor::FrameAnimation playerDown;
playerDown.addFrame(10.0f, sf::IntRect(0 , 0, 32, 32));
playerDown.addFrame(10.0f, sf::IntRect(32, 0, 32, 32));
playerDown.addFrame(10.0f, sf::IntRect(64, 0, 32, 32));

thor::FrameAnimation playerLeft;
playerLeft.addFrame(20.0f, sf::IntRect(0 , 32, 32, 32));
playerLeft.addFrame(20.0f, sf::IntRect(32, 32, 32, 32));
playerLeft.addFrame(20.0f, sf::IntRect(64, 32, 32, 32));

thor::FrameAnimation playerRight;
playerRight.addFrame(30.0f, sf::IntRect(0 , 64, 32, 32));
playerRight.addFrame(30.0f, sf::IntRect(32, 64, 32, 32));
playerRight.addFrame(30.0f, sf::IntRect(64, 64, 32, 32));

thor::FrameAnimation playerUp;
playerUp.addFrame(40.0f, sf::IntRect(0 , 96, 32, 32));
playerUp.addFrame(40.0f, sf::IntRect(32, 96, 32, 32));
playerUp.addFrame(40.0f, sf::IntRect(64, 96, 32, 32));

thor::AnimationMap<sf::Sprite, std::string> playerAMap;
playerAMap.addAnimation("down" , playerDown , sf::seconds(2.0f));
playerAMap.addAnimation("left" , playerLeft , sf::seconds(3.0f));
playerAMap.addAnimation("right", playerRight, sf::seconds(4.0f));
playerAMap.addAnimation("up"   , playerUp   , sf::seconds(5.0f));

thor::Animator<sf::Sprite, std::string> playerAnimator = thor::Animator<sf::Sprite, 
std::string>::Animator(playerAMap);

sf::Clock animFrameTime;

sf::RenderWindow window;
window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 450), "Placeholder", sf::Style::Default);

while (window.isOpen())
{

// here's movement direction checking, event handling, dealing with movement overall

// let's say we dont use any of that now and we want to play just the "up" animation

playerAnimator.play() << "up" << thor::Playback::loop("up");

playerAnimator.update(animFrameTime.restart());
playerAnimator.animate(sprPlayer);

window.draw(sprPlayer);
}

return 0;
}
```

As I said, the behaviour of that code is it just plays the first frame of up animation (in this case the upper-left frame of the spritesheet).

For "left" animation it plays the first frame of the second row, and for all the others respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

```
texPlayer.create(96, 128);
```

is not needed, as you immediately load a file and thus overwrite the texture. `sf::Texture::create()` is mainly useful when you edit the texture after loading it, or use it for low-level OpenGL.

The `thor::Animator` can be understood to have two modes of operation, each of which covers a few methods:

- **Select/switch animation:** `play()`, `stop()`, `queue()`
  This should be invoked only when you want to change the animation playing (a character starts to move/attack) or when you want to stop a playing animation (character stands still).
- **Update state and apply graphics:** `update()`, `animate()`
  This should be applied every graphics frame. If you want deterministic animation behavior (your animations require constant progress), you should call `update()` in a fixed-time logic step.

Those are already all the methods that `thor::Animator` offers, see [official documentation](http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/documentation/v2.1/classthor_1_1_animator.html).

The mistake in your code is that you call `play()` in every frame, thus restarting the animation constantly. What you should do instead is call `play()` before the `while` loop. Since you specified `thor::Playback::loop()`, the animation will be looping as long as you update the animator.